# why does UINT_MAX + 3 always equal 2?

Tags: c

Can someone help me, I've written a small `C` program to output the value of UINT_MAX + 3, and tested it on both a mac, and ubuntu, and it keeps giving me `2`

Thank you

Comment: UINT_MAX is the maximum value an unsigned integer can have. In the C standard, unsigned integers are defined to wraparound. This is well documented, and your results are as required by the spec. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the way it is defined in th C standard. Unsigned integers have modular arithmetic. Incrementing the largest unsigned integer of any type by 1 results in 0. Incrementing by 2 yields 1. And so on.

By the same token, subtracting 1 from 0 gives you the largest value of that unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to add 3 to UINT_MAX and obtain a larger value, then you need to use a larger integer type than the type for which UINT_MAX is defined for your compiler.  Unfortunately, the way that you do that depends on your compiler.  For example using Visual C++ on Windows, an int is 32 bits, so UINT_MAX is 4,294,967,295.  In Visual C++, you specify a 64-bit integer using the type __int64, so writing:

```
unsigned __int64 n;
n=(unsigned __int64)UINT_MAX+3;
printf("%I64i\n",n);
```

...will print the desired value, 4,294,967,298.

Comment: To print `unsigned __int64`, better to use `printf("%I64u\n", n);`